# HIberante Embedded Id with field from bi-directional ManyToOne Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Cars implements java.io.Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int number;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car", referencedColumnName = "number")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private Set<Models> modelses;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "models")
public class Models implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "car", column = @Column(name = "car", nullable = false))
        ,
        @AttributeOverride(name = "model", column = @Column(name = "model", nullable = false))
    })
    private ModelsId id;

    @Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "car")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Cars car;

    ...

}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class ModelsId implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int car;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int model;

    ...
}
```

I have a case in which if I have to delete a Cars record or a Models record then I pass the array of Cars containing only those Cars and Models which I want to save in the database. All entries other than the ones in list are to be deleted.
While my saveList method is working fine if I am saving the list without deleting any item or I am adding any item in the Cars or Models but it fails if I want to delete some Models entries.

I am getting the exception (with hibernate logging enabled):

```
update models set car=null where car=? and model=?
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [7]
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
```

Here is the method where I save the list in the database

```
public void saveList(List<CarsDTO> carsDTOs) {
  List<Cars> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CarsDTO carDTO : carsDTOs) {
            cars.add(new Cars(carDTO));
        }
        carsRepo.save(cars);
       }
```

Comment: As i am understanding from above, this error may occur due to concurrency. you can try it once by  setting the delete operation in another method or request.
Many times the compiler fails to differentiate.
Also make sure that you are using transnational annotation on serviceIMPL.

Comment: @divyanshugupta I have tried the Transactional annotation also but it gave the same error as above.

Comment: what for do you need @AttributeOverrides?

Comment: @conrad well the entity structure and relationships are legacy code and i am trying to write the saveList method mentioned in the question

Comment: Can you post your carsRepo class ? The problem is in the method save. Probebly you try to bind more params than you have

Comment: @Massimo carsRepo extends JpaRepository

Comment: Is very difficult for me tryiing a resolution without understanding what happens with deleting. Anyway, did you try the @MapsId annotation on private Cars car; , instead of AttributeOverride ?

Comment: @Massimo if i am using @MapsId(value="car") on  private Cars car then I am getting the exception: *Unknown column 'modelses1_.car_number' in 'field list's*

Comment: somewhere yuo define a feld carNumber ?i

Comment: @massimo `number` is the primary key of the `Car` entity